# ESO: about crown store horses

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I was wondering if I should buy a  "premium " horse in the crown store, and I have a few unanswered questions:

- Do they reset my current horse's stats?
- Can I switch between the 2 horses?
- Are they unlocked for all characters?
- Lastly, do they get better starting stats like the 42.7k horses in the stables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your "horse stats" are bound to your character, not your mount. So if my character has speed 60, it doesn't matter whether the horse, senche, or camel is active. My character always has speed 60.
- You can switch between all your unlocked mounts (no matter whether purchased with gold or crowns) at any time, simply opening your *Collection* and using the *Mounts* sub category.
- All unlocked mounts are unlocked account wide. In fact there aren't any character-specific unlocks except riding lessons, inventory space, and werewolf/vampire bites.
- All mounts have the exact same stats. You're only switching appearance.